# Exception in thread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, c3p0

I recently got the following messages in our logs followed by a Application Server is crash. I am not sure what to make of this and would really appreciate any guidance.

```
Exception in thread "Task-Thread-for-com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPerTaskAsynchronousRunner@6a1a2b5b" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory
at java.nio.Bits.reserveMemory(Bits.java:658)
at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(DirectByteBuffer.java:123)
at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(ByteBuffer.java:306)
at com.amazon.jdbc.communications.channels.MessagesSocketChannel.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGClient.connect(Unknown Source)
at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.amazon.redshift.core.PGJDBCConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at com.amazon.jdbc.common.BaseConnectionFactory.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at com.amazon.jdbc.common.AbstractDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:134)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPerTaskAsynchronousRunner$TaskThread.run(ThreadPerTaskAsynchronousRunner.java:255)

Exception in thread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazon/redshift/exceptions/PGJDBCMessageKey
at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGClient.connect(Unknown Source)
at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.amazon.redshift.core.PGJDBCConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at com.amazon.jdbc.common.BaseConnectionFactory.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at com.amazon.jdbc.common.AbstractDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:134)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
atcom.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
```

We are using Spring , hibernate and c3p0 with the following Configration

```
<bean id="redShiftDS" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <!-- access -->
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.amazon.redshift.jdbc41.Driver" />
    <property name="user">
            <value>${redshift.user}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value>${redshift.pwd}</value>
        </property>     

        <property name="jdbcUrl">
            <value>${redshift.URL}</value>
        </property>


    <!-- pool sizing -->
    <property name="initialPoolSize" value="3" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="6" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="25" />
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="3" />
    <property name="maxStatements" value="0" />

    <!-- retries -->
    <property name="acquireRetryAttempts" value="30" />
    <property name="acquireRetryDelay" value="1000" /> <!-- 1s -->
    <property name="breakAfterAcquireFailure" value="false" />

    <!-- refreshing connections -->
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="180" /> <!-- 3min -->
    <property name="maxConnectionAge" value="10" /> <!-- 1h -->

    <!-- timeouts and testing -->
    <property name="checkoutTimeout" value="5000" /> <!-- 5s -->
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="60" /> <!-- 60 -->
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="true" />
        <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin" value="true" />
</bean>
        <bean id="redShiftSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="redShiftDS" />
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.ghx.mi">
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.auto_close_session">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">30</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                 <prop key="hibernate.autoReconnect">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.autoReconnectForPools">true</prop>    
                <prop key="hibernate.is-connection-validation-required">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

we use Java 7 & Tomcat 7.0

Comment: The error shows missing class `com/amazon/redshift/exceptions/PGJDBCMessageKey`. Do check for the missing library jar for this class.

Comment: @VivekSingh one day before it working fine now only i got this error in which jar i will use to solve this error. this is my recent error. its in production server

Comment: This has to do with redshiftjdbc jar. Did you by any chance made any configuration changes in your application,

Comment: @VivekSingh i am using RedshiftJDBC41-1.1.6.1006.jar

Comment: Is this jar present in the lib folder in the deployed application. Can you check once. Also check if two versions of the same jar are not present

Comment: @VivekSingh My application worked fine last two month. yesterday only i was add c3p0 configuration.    The jar under Lib folder only,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94061/discussion-between-vivek-singh-and-sivakumar-m).

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions:

1) Make sure that c3p0's jar file is in the same "place", from a CLASSPATH perspective, as the library that should contain `com.amazon.redshift.exceptions.PGJDBCMessageKey` (probably your RedshiftJDBC41-1.1.6.1006.jar) In other words, don't place the redshift jar in an application server lib directory but c3p0's jar files in a web application lib directory, or something like that. They should be in logically the same CLASSPATH.

2) Add the following property to your c3p0 config:

```
<property name="contextClassLoaderSource" value="library" />
```

This will ensure that c3p0 Threads try to load classes using the same ClassLoader that loaded the library, ie the same logical CLASSPATH as the one containing c3p0.
(See [the docs](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#contextClassLoaderSource).)

3) Fix this, from

```
<property name="maxConnectionAge" value="10" /> <!-- 1h -->
```

to this

```
<property name="maxConnectionAge" value="3600" /> <!-- 1h, really this time -->
```

10 seconds is much, much too fast to be expiring Connections, and that will lead to churning, memory stress, and miscellaneous misbehavior.